# Stifling "file or directory not found" messages in popen

Tags: c, linux, popen

I'm using popen to run a system script, like so:

```
snprintf(cmd, MAX_PATH, "/myscript -q | grep -i %s", deviceName);
FILE *res = popen(cmd, "r");
```

If the script is not found, the program carries on its merry way. However, a "file or directory not found" message is displayed, which seems like an error even though in my intended usage it isn't.

Is there a way to silence this message, or should I just call `ls | grep -i myscript` before running this line?

Comment: Does just `/myscript -q` succeed?  What is `deviceName`?

Comment: /myscript -q doesn't succeed, which is the point: the script doesn't exist, which to me is the same as the function not finding the device, which is an acceptable result that shouldn't make my program print an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `/bin/sh` is a POSIX shell, or a reasonably recent Bourne shell variant, you can redirect standard output within the command before executing the actual command. You only need to prepend `exec 2>/dev/null ;` before the command you wish to execute.

Here is how I'd personally do this:

```
/* Shell syntax for redirecting standard error to /dev/null, to
 * silence any errors. If /bin/sh does not support this, you can
 * simply replace it with an empty string.
*/
#define  POPEN_STDERR_NULL "exec 2>/dev/null ;"

...

snprintf(cmd, MAX_PATH, POPEN_STDERR_NULL "/myscript -q | grep -i -e '%s'", deviceName);
FILE *res = popen(cmd, "r");
```

The `popen()` command uses `/bin/sh` internally to run the specified command.  The above works for all `/bin/sh` variants I can test, including Linux and SunOS 5.10, so it should be quite portable.  (In other words, `dash`, `bash`, and SunOS 5.10 `sh` all work fine with it.)

Since you'll need to recompile the application for any nonstandard systems, you can always edit the macro to omit the prefix. (You can easily add a test to `Makefile` magic to automatically omit it if necessary, *if* you ever find such a system.)

Note that I modified the parameter substitution in the `snprintf()` call. It will work for any `deviceName` that does *not* contain a single quote. Any single quotes in `deviceName` should be replaced with the string `'"'"'` before the `snprintf()` call.

Questions?

Comment: This won't turn off the error stream for the rest of the application's run, would it?

Comment: No, the redirection only affects the command being run with `popen()`. The application can use `stderr` normally before, during, and after; it is not affected by this at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if you can stifle the message. The error is a standard Linux error which is printed onto the standard error stream. You can keep FD '2' which is the file descriptor for Standard error. So maybe you can close this FD.

However, I must warn you that this will prevent any errors from being printed for the rest of your program.

A better way would be to do this:
snprintf(cmd, MAX_PATH, "/myscript -q | grep -i %s 2> dummyfile", deviceName);

This will redirect the error to a dummy file which you delete immediately.

So exercise caution and decide what you would like to do...

Cheers,
VSN